# Is there any way to keep the properties file external to the ear/jars and module for WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss6.x

I have an application, which refers to a MY_ PRODUCT_CONF_DIR/mycustom.properties file which has some key value pairs which needs to be external to the ear, war or jars deployed on my WildFly. Earlier  in Jboss 6.1.0. we did it in a tricky way. The jboss 6.1.0, have a collection of URLs, visible to CL loading the server.

For example ( https://repository.jboss.org/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-distribution/6.1.0.Final/, refer to jboss-6.1.0.Final-src\main\src\main\java\org\jboss\Main.java )

```
  // Define a Set URLs to have visible to the CL loading the Server
  final Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<URL>();
  ..........
  urls.add(new File(MY_ PRODUCT_CONF_DIR)).toURI().toURL());   // I have added the DIR 

  .........
  // Make a ClassLoader to be used in loading the server
  final URL[] urlArray = urls.toArray(new URL[]{});
  final ClassLoader loadingCl = new URLClassLoader(urlArray, tccl);

  // Load the server
  server = JBossASServer.class.cast(ServerFactory.createServer(DEFAULT_AS_SERVER_IMPL_CLASS_NAME, loadingCl));
```

In my code, I read the properties file from ClassLoader

```
URLClassLoader ucl = (URLClassLoader) loader;
url = ucl.findResource(propertiesResource);
final InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
..........
```

So, is there any option to retain this mechanism? Can I add my CONFIG_DIR in the ModuleClassLoader as a URLClassLoader?

Is there any way to keep the properties file external to the ear/jars and module path?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your properties file in a module and load it that way without having to use a URLClassLoader for getResource or getInputStream . Another way would be to specify the path to your properties files in some system property and then just do a Properties.load(Files.newInputStream(myPath))